# XSLT usage to reach attribute value in structured elements with the same name

Tags: xml, xslt

I hope someone can help me with this problem to which i found no solution at the moment.
I am using XSLT for the first time to convert some XML. The trouble I am finding is using a template to get to the **Message** element with the attribute value. 
BTW i'm not generating the XML and I can't change its structure

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ns1:Message >
    <ns1:Notification> 
        <ns22:Message>
        <ns1:Message value="timestamp">
        </ns1:Message>
        </ns22:Message>
    </ns1:Notification>
    </ns1:Message>
```

Comment: Is that the full XML? Because it seems to be missing namespace declarations which you would need to parse it properly. I'm surprised you can even load it without getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your namespace declarations are just missing from the example you have given, you can access the timestamp with XSLT that looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ns1="http://ns1.com/"
  xmlns:ns22="http://ns22.com/"> 
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="/ns1:Message/ns1:Notification/ns22:Message/ns1:Message/@value"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've obviously just made up some urls for the namespaces, but you get the general idea.

If your XML document really is missing namespace declarations, it's not well formed in which case I don't think there is anything you can do with it.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The XML is well formed I just forgot to put the URLs for the namespaces (those ones are just made up). However, this doesn't work although i put all of the namespace URLs on the XSLT. What's weird also is that I got templates working and picking data without using ns1 or ns22 when i try to create a template to search for "Message" it returns nothing. Is there a way to do it with a template in this scenario? BTW i'm doing this in Java

Comment: Can you update your question with the real namespaces. Because I've tested this exact xslt on a document just like yours (only with my namespaces) and it worked as expected.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't give out the actual file with the real namespaces (confidentiality and all that). I tried to make small examples where this could work and it doesn't. I am trying to get it as template but for some reason it cancels out all the other template while the others work on their own. I think it's to do with the fact that it's badly formed XML with Message being put there with different namespaces

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem thanks James for the help. Your answer was quite insightful and helped figure it out. I tried to avoid using Namespaces and giving the direct Path as in

```
  <xsl:value-of select="/Message/Notification/Message/Message/@value"/>
```

and it gets me the data I want. However I have tried to do some more fancy stuff such as

**I WOULD LIKE TO STRESS THAT HAVING THE NAMESPACES ON THE PATH DIDN'T GET ME THE DATA ON MY FILE** this might not be everyone's case

```
        <xsl:template match="Item">   
      <xsl:if test="@Name = 'Token'">
                <xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>   
          </xsl:if>
      </xsl:template>
```

and it worked for **item** element

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <ns1:Message >
            <ns1:Notification> 
              <ns22:Message>
               <ns1:Message value="timestamp">
                 <ns1:item Token=1643512>
                 <ns1:item Token2=44553512>
                   </ns1:Message>
                </ns22:Message>
             </ns1:Notification>
               </ns1:Message>
```

So making a ***template*** to reach that **Message** tag is what I haven't managed to get to work.
Though the solution above is a nice and dirty way to get what I want. If someone can let me know why making a template in a similar fashion as above to get to the Message tag doesn't work and **breaks the whole xslt**. Thanks everyone is advance

Comment: It just occurred to me that it's possible your xslt processor doesn't support namespaces, or it's an option that you need to enable. That would explain why that top query works with no namespace prefixes and why you could never get my answer to work.